# WebPermission Exception even though I'm in Full trust

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest, trust, full-trust

I'm trying to do what I thought was a simple HttpWebRequest (the code is deep inside a dll so I can't give a small code snippet, but it should be relatively simple), but I'm getting a security exception:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

I've checked and everything is running with Full trust, and have tried setting this in the web.config.  But I've no idea what could be creating the error.

Any ideas??

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace of this exception? Is there anything special about this particular web request? Do other web requests work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer to this here:

http://dbvt.com/blog/post/AspNetHostingPermission-Security-Exception-Fix-with-Ajax-in-IIS7.aspx

Basically set the application pool to "Load User Profile"